# jQuery Validation and Form Plugin Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have no luck running this both plugin in the same page the 
Form: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/  and  Validation: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

every time I check the error console in firefox it says "jQuery is not defined"

sorry i forgot to add the header.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jqueryValidation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="Data.asp">
<input type="text" name="ISNo" id="ISNo" class="required"/>
<input type="text" name="ISDate" id="ISDate" class="required"/>
<input type="submit" value="save!">
</form>

<form name="Search" id="Search" method="post" action="Search.asp">
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname"/>
<input type="text" name="txtaddress" id="txtaddress"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: are you sure the path "../jQuery/jquery.js" corresponds to jQuery.js actual position? it's a relative path. beware!

Comment: yes, im sure i have the right path

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a clash, but more it can't find the `jQuery` object.

What does this alert?

```
alert(typeof jQuery);
```

If you get `undefined`, double check your paths.